# The mysqli/mysql extension is missing

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a problem. After installing php 5.6 and php 7.1 (`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`) I wanted to install phpmyadmin. After installing phpmyadmin the next error shows:`The mysqli/mysql extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration`. When I uninstall phpmyadmin, this error is still displaying. Where is the problem? (Ubuntu 16.04)
[Screen of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1M72p.png)

Comment: Did you install the correspondiing plugins from that PPA, such as `php5.6-mysql` or `php7.1-mysql`?

Comment: Yes, I do but now everything is going. When I restarted server, phpmyadmin start works.